# Build Extended-jSS7

Tags: maven, build, restcomm

I am trying to build the Extended-jss7 from https://github.com/PAiC-team/Extended-jSS7.

I am getting stuck on building Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Api  see below error "code".

It seems that the SCTP API 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT is not available on URLs below

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/

And I have no authentication info to the URL below from PAiC so I can check.

https://maven.pkg.github.com/PAiC-team/*/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/

Any ideas or suggestion on how to workaround this issue?

Thanks in advance!

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Api :: m3ua-api 8.3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://maven.pkg.github.com/PAiC-team/*/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/mobicents/protocols/sctp/sctp-api/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.mobicents.protocols.sctp:sctp-api:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/PAiC-team/*): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.mobicents.protocols.sctp:sctp-api:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https://maven.pkg.github.com/PAiC-team/* was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of github has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.mobicents.protocols.sctp:sctp-api:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/PAiC-team/*): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Extended SCTP (https://github.com/PAiC-team/extended-sctp) and build it locally which will save the artifacts to the local maven repository. You can then build the Extended jSS7 that will use the maven local repository instead of pulling one from the Github packages.

To build Extended SCTP use

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Prelease -Drelease.name=sctp
```

The other option is to use this link https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry to configure your maven settings to pull the package from Github package registry.

*JDK 11 is recommended for both the Extended SCTP and the Extended jSS7*